# How to find out if a directory exists on Delphi XE2 *correctly*?

Tags: delphi, filesystems, delphi-xe2

I simply need to check if a directory exists! But if the directory is "E:\Test" where E: is CD/DVD drive and there is no disk inserted on it, I see the following Delphi and Windows issues.

**The first method:**

```
function DirExists(Name: string): Boolean;
var
  Code: Integer;
begin
  Code := GetFileAttributesW(PChar(Name));
  Result := (Code <> -1) and (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY and Code <> 0);
end;
```

It gives `Range Check Error`. I can't use `{$RANGECHECKS OFF}`, `{$RANGECHECKS ON}` blocks because:

1. It breaks the current state of `$RANGECHECKS` option.
2. We will see another system error `Drive is not ready` instead `Range Check Error`. But I simply need to check if directory exists without any error dialogs for user.

**The second method:**

```
if DirectoryExists(Name, True) then ...
```

This function returns `True` for non-existing `E:\Test` directory on empty CD/DVD drive. So can't use it because it works incorrectly.

But then, how to find out if a directory exists?

*P.S. I think the error exists with any CD/DVD drive. But I am using Windows 7 x64 on VMWare Fusion 5 under Mac OS X 10.8.4 with external CD/DVD drive.*

Comment: So weird - `DirectoryExists()` indeed returns true in my PC for an empty DVD drive. Using Delphi XE and Windows 8.

Comment: How do I correctly write it?

Comment: This is a longstanding bug with directoryexists. [See here](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=105954). I don't know a solution off hand.

Comment: In XE3 they added a check for `ERROR_NOT_READY` to "fix" this. All seems very bogus to me.

Comment: Rik, I can see `Resolution: Fixed (Resolution Comments)` on your link. Why do you think it isn't fixed on XE3+?

Comment: Where can I find `SysUtils.pas` code from XE3 or XE4 on the Internet?

Comment: @Altaveron: You can find it at http://www.embarcadero.com/delphi, when you upgrade to XE3 or XE4. Posting the file via the internet would be a violation of Embarcadero's licensing and copyright. It also wouldn't work, as it depends on changes made in other units as well that would not be available in earlier versions.

Comment: @Altaveron it shouldn't be fixed in XE3+; it should be fixed in XE2. When I sold software any problem that was caused by something on our end was fixed, for free, for the life of the software. When you sell software you say "The product does X". If it doesn't do X (bug), that's lying. Refusing to make good on the deal (fixing software so that it does X) is cheating the customer, IMHO. EMBT has a racket going on with requiring updates to fix bugs and it's one of many reasons open source dev tools are beating them silly.

Comment: @alcalde It's trivially easy to fix the bug for yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Delphi XE2 to Delphi XE3+ or use the following function:

```
function DirectoryExistsDelphiXE2(const Directory: string; FollowLink: Boolean = True): Boolean;
var
  Code: Cardinal;
  Handle: THandle;
  LastError: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := False;
  Code := GetFileAttributes(PChar(Directory));

  if Code <> INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES then
  begin
    if faSymLink and Code = 0 then
      Result := faDirectory and Code <> 0
    else
    begin
      if FollowLink then
      begin
        Handle := CreateFile(PChar(Directory), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
          OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
        if Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
        begin
          CloseHandle(Handle);
          Result := faDirectory and Code <> 0;
        end;
      end
      else if faDirectory and Code <> 0 then
        Result := True
      else
      begin
        Handle := CreateFile(PChar(Directory), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
          OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
        if Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
        begin
          CloseHandle(Handle);
          Result := False;
        end
        else
          Result := True;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    LastError := GetLastError;
    Result := (LastError <> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) and
      (LastError <> ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND) and
      (LastError <> ERROR_INVALID_NAME) and
      (LastError <> ERROR_BAD_NETPATH) and
      (LastError <> ERROR_NOT_READY);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This doesn't address the other part of the question.

Comment: This part. *We will see another system error Drive is not ready instead Range Check Error. But I simply need to check if directory exists without any error dialogs for user.*

Comment: I don't see any errors with DirectoryExists() from XE3 - it works as required.

Comment: I also, in my trials, did not see the system error dialogs, even on XE2. The changes between XE2 and XE3 implementation of `DirectoryExists` will have no impact on the system error dialogs. If you do whatever it is that provokes those dialogs again, even with the XE3 code, the dialogs will still appear. You really should heed the advice given by MS and add `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS`. Surely you'd rather handle any errors in your code rather than show those dialogs? Or do you actually on second thoughts want to see the system error dialogs?

Comment: It seems likely that the system error dialog was not raised by `DirectoryExists` but was instead raised by some subsequent action that was happening because of the output from `DirectoryExists` being not what you expected. However, just because you fix this one failure mode in `DirectoryExists` does not mean that they are all fixed. If you don't suppress system errors, then do not be surprised if they appear in some other scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You can just fix your function so that it doesn't cause range check errors:

```
function DirExists(Name: string): Boolean;
var
  Code: DWORD;
begin
  Code := GetFileAttributes(PChar(Name));
  Result := (Code <> INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) 
    and (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY and Code <> 0);
end;
```

The range check errors are due to you mixing signed and unsigned types. Remy also points out the very useful trick to set compiler options and then restore to the prevailing state. That's a good trick to learn, but you don't need it here.

The XE3 implementation of DirectoryExists is modified to address the problem that you have encountered. So, if using XE3+ was an option, you should take it.

---

To suppress the system error dialogs call this at process startup:

```
procedure SetProcessErrorMode;
var
  Mode: DWORD;
begin
  Mode := SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
  SetErrorMode(Mode or SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
end;
```

Doing this is best practise as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621.aspx):

> Best practice is that all applications call the process-
>   wide SetErrorMode function with a parameter of SEM_
>   FAILCRITICALERRORS at startup. This is to prevent error mode
>   dialogs from hanging the application.

Comment: But will error dialogs be suppressed on all project? It's impossible to break logic of the entire project just to check if a directory exists on 1 unit.

Comment: @Altaveron In that case call `SetThreadErrorMode` instead (if on Win7), and restore the error mode afterwards. However, I think that you do want to add `FAILCRITICALERRORS` if your program is an executable. The default error mode is to maintain ancient back compat. You don't ever want those dialogs shown. You want the function call to fail and for you to report errors your own way.

Comment: @Altaveron No matter what, you are going to need to face up to dealing with the error mode. If you don't add in `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` then you will see the dialog that you want to suppress. `SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` is the way to suppress that dialog.

Comment: David, your method is really hard to understand. So by boss will not believe that I need a lot of time to learn error modes just to check if a directory exists...

Comment: @Altaveron I'm not sure I can help you there. Either you want to suppress the dialog, or you don't. Anyway, isn't it enough to point your boss at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680621.aspx): *The system does not display the critical-error-handler message box. Instead, the system sends the error to the calling process.
Best practice is that all applications call the process-wide SetErrorMode function with a parameter of SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS at startup. This is to prevent error mode dialogs from hanging the application.*

Comment: I am not absolutely sure but I saw `Range Check Error` with DWORD type too.

Comment: I can't comment on your code that I cannot see. However, I can guarantee that the code in my answer will never raise a range checking bounds error. And I can guarantee that from static analysis. If that's not enough you can check the code that is emitted. And you will see that there are no calls to `BoundErr`. So the compiler is also able to guarantee no range errors through its static analysis.

Answer (score 3):

David has the right answer in regards to avoiding the range check error.  But if you don't want to do that, you can still turn off/on `{$RANGECHECKS}` manually, just use `{$IFOPT}` to do it conditionally so surrounding code is not affected, eg:

```
function DirExists(Name: string): Boolean;
var
  Code: Integer;
begin
  {$IFOPT R+}
    {$DEFINE _RPlusWasEnabled}
    {$R-}
  {$ENDIF}

  Code := GetFileAttributesW(PChar(Name));
  Result := (Code <> -1) and (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY and Code <> 0);

  {$IFDEF _RPlusWasEnabled}
    {$UNDEF _RPlusWasEnabled}
    {$R+}
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

With that said, checking the result of `GetFileAttributes()` for `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` alone is not enough.  A directory could exist but just not be accessible.  That is why the RTL's `DirectoryExists()` function checks `GetLastError()` for multiple error codes (`ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, `ERROR_BAD_NETPATH`, `ERROR_NOT_READY`, etc) looking for that possible condition.  Another thing `DirectoryExists()` can do is optionally check if the specified path is actually a shortcut to a directory, and if so check if the target directory exists or not.

**Update:** here is the implementation of `SysUtils.DirectoryExists()` in XE3:

```
function DirectoryExists(const Directory: string; FollowLink: Boolean = True): Boolean;
{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
var
  Code: Cardinal;
  Handle: THandle;
  LastError: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := False;
  Code := GetFileAttributes(PChar(Directory));

  if Code <> INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES then
  begin
    if faSymLink and Code = 0 then
      Result := faDirectory and Code <> 0
    else
    begin
      if FollowLink then
      begin
        Handle := CreateFile(PChar(Directory), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
          OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
        if Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
        begin
          CloseHandle(Handle);
          Result := faDirectory and Code <> 0;
        end;
      end
      else if faDirectory and Code <> 0 then
        Result := True
      else
      begin
        Handle := CreateFile(PChar(Directory), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
          OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);
        if Handle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
        begin
          CloseHandle(Handle);
          Result := False;
        end
        else
          Result := True;
      end;
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    LastError := GetLastError;
    Result := (LastError <> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) and
      (LastError <> ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND) and
      (LastError <> ERROR_INVALID_NAME) and
      (LastError <> ERROR_BAD_NETPATH) and
      (LastError <> ERROR_NOT_READY);
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
{$IFDEF POSIX}
var
  StatBuf, LStatBuf: _stat;
  Success: Boolean;
  M: TMarshaller;
begin
  Success := stat(M.AsAnsi(Directory, CP_UTF8).ToPointer, StatBuf) = 0;
  Result := Success and S_ISDIR(StatBuf.st_mode);

  if not Result and (lstat(M.AsAnsi(Directory, CP_UTF8).ToPointer, LStatBuf) = 0) and
    S_ISLNK(LStatBuf.st_mode) then
  begin
    if Success then
      Result := S_ISDIR(StatBuf.st_mode)
    else if not FollowLink then
      Result := True;
  end;
end;
{$ENDIF POSIX}
```

The implementation in XE4 is the same with only one difference - the Windows version also includes a check for `LastError <> ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME` when calling `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Thanks for your method! Do you have XE3 or XE4 installed? Please may you write here `DiretoryExists()` code from it?

Comment: @Remy I cannot see any reason not to check last error against 0.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: An error code from `GetFileAttributes()` simply means that attributes could not be retrieved, but you would have to look at the error code to find out *WHY* the attributes could not be retrieved. Only certain error codes occur when the directory really does not exist. Other error codes mean the directory does exist but cannot be accessed. The purpose of a `DirectoryExists()` type of function is to determine **existence**, not **accessibility**, so the error code needs to be analyzed accordingly.

Comment: @Altaveron: the source code for `DirectoryExists()` has been added to my answer.

Comment: It would seem to me that Emba have got the logic the wrong way round. If they must do it this way then they should be checking for the error codes that mean "exists, but not accessible". But that approach is flawed still. If not accessible then the code cannot check whether or not the object is a directory. So accessibility is still going to influence outcome. I would make the function return false whenever attributes cannot be read. I think the function is badly designed. If it was well designed they'd have been able to get a version that works by now.

Comment: `DirectoryExists()` did not start looking at error codes until Delphi XE (`FileExists()` has been looking at error codes since Delphi 2007). Prior to that, it still sometimes reported incorrect results, more so because it would report False for folders that actually existed. Looking at error codes has helped make it more accurate, so it can return True for folders that do exist but are just not accessible. There are only so many error codes that say "this path really does not exist", but apparently each new release finds another error code to add to the list.  Blame Microsoft for that.

Comment: What Embarcadero should do is update `FileExists()` and `DirectoryExists()` to use `PathFileExists()` and `PathIsDirectory()` instead of `GetFileAttributes()`. They have existed since Win2K.

Comment: I just created a ticket in QC: [#117699](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=117699).

Comment: `PathFileExists` and `PathIsDirectory` appear to be limited to `MAX_PATH`

Comment: Are you just speculating based on what the documentation claims, or did you actually try them with paths prepended with `"\\?\"` and they failed for legitimate paths?